# Is there any problem in released app if I leave all print statement while debugging app for future reference?

Tags: debugging, flutter, release

I am developing an app from Flutter framework for a client.
As I am new in app development so just tell me -

Is there will be any problem or not in my released app if I leave all of those print statement while debugging?

Comment: I don't think so, and I guess it will be good practice to console the important data to help you debug the app in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

It makes very little difference. 
Leave them on the app for better understandability of code.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what Flutter engineer Jonah Williams from Google says on this matter:

> I would recommend not leaving print statements in your code. If you
>   need generic logging support and want to disable it for production,
>   you could use something like https://github.com/dart-lang/logging and
>   then disable the root logger for production

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20806